# takePersistableUriPermission Access lost after documentfile deleted

Tags: java, android, uri, storage-access-framework, documentfile

After picking a folder with

```
registerForActivityResult( new ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree ...
```

I'm taking writing permission on it

```
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Later in the app, I have written files to the user selected dir

```
saveDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(App.getInstance(), Uri.parse(uriStringSavedInPrefs));
```

The problem is: when I create a file its created successfully

```
DocumentFile finalResFile =saveDir.createFile("image/*",resFileName);
```

But then I delete it later and it gets deleted too

```
DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(App.getInstance(),finalResFile .getUri()).delete();
```

Bute later I try to create a new file again and I get an error

```
DocumentFile finalResFile =saveDir.createFile("image/*",someNewFileName);

Failed query: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3A.AndroidData/document/primary%3A.AndroidData/children from pid=32273, uid=10546 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
 Failed to create document
```

Why is the write access getting lost after deleting a single file on it?

Comment: `when I create a file its created successfully But when I delete it with` ? The file?

Comment: `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(App.getInstance(),uri).delete()` It is pretty unclear what you try to delete. It cannot be a file as you cannot use fromTreeUri then. Please show cimplete code.

Comment: Have updated the question>please check

Comment: You cannot use fromTreeUri if you delete a file. I expect exceptions.

Comment: What about finalResFile.delete()?

Comment: I'm NOT  creating already deleted file.I'm just repeating the procedure of creating newfile with new name

Comment: Do not use fromTreeUri to delete a file. Was the directory deleted too?

Comment: i figured that out but why?  Is it documented somewhere to not use the delete method of a document file???

Comment: Who said that? And why didnt you react on my suggestion: finalResFile.delete() ?

Comment: You said that. "Do not use fromTreeUri to delete a file" and : finalResFile.delete()  works but I can no longer write to the user picked uri

Answer (score 1):

If I delete documentfile like this,I lose access,still don't know why (I'm not deleting the user picked directory,just a file I created inside it)

```
DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(App.getInstance(),uri).delete();
```

Using this to delete file somehow works (I dont lose access write access)

```
DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(App.getInstance().getContentResolver(),uri);
```

I hate SAF